# LSTM Model Issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, lstm

For an Assignment I'm looking at different prediction models of stocks to compare their performance. In this case my goal is for the model to rely on prediction input parameters rather than the last value.
I'm trying to implement a LSTM Model but always get the following error:
'ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1281, 1300]'

Anyone suggest how to overcome this issue?

Please see the code below:

```
y = df_DJI['Close'].iloc[1:].dropna()
X = df_DJI.drop(['Close'],axis=1).iloc[1:].dropna()

look_back = 40
forward_days = 10
num_periods = 20

from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#model = keras.Sequential()

X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
NUM_NEURONS_FirstLayer = 128
NUM_NEURONS_SecondLayer = 64
EPOCHS = 220

#Build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(NUM_NEURONS_FirstLayer,input_shape=(look_back,1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(NUM_NEURONS_SecondLayer,input_shape=(NUM_NEURONS_FirstLayer,1)))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=EPOCHS,validation_data=(X_validate,y_validate),shuffle=True,batch_size=2, verbose=2)
```

The error output is:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-0312bf3a55cf> in <module>
     18 #model = keras.Sequential()
     19 
---> 20 X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
     21 NUM_NEURONS_FirstLayer = 128
     22 NUM_NEURONS_SecondLayer = 64

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2125         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2126 
-> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2128 
   2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    291     """
    292     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 293     check_consistent_length(*result)
    294     return result
    295 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    255     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    258 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1281, 1300]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error raises since the input of `train_test_split` has to have the same length/shape (see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)).
Therefore I assume that dropping nans leads to unequal shapes of `X` and `y` since one column other than `'Close'` includes more nans.

**Solution:** Drop the nans before splitting to `X` and `y` by:

```
df_DJI.dropna(inplace=True)
y = df_DJI["Close"].iloc[1:]
X = df_DJI.drop(["Close"], axis=1).iloc[1:]
```